# Telerik ASP.NET MVC TabStrip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I'm using ASP.NET MVC/Telerik ASP.NET MVC Server side controls.

1. Created a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web App (Basic)
2. Followed all the [pre-requisites](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4).
3. Created a tabStrip using [this tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/tabstrip/overview). (ASP.NET MVC/.cshtml)

The Tab-strip gets rendered but if I click on any of the tabs the content does not show up. But I see the URL change being appended by the tab strip.

On another front, if I need to use Telerik ASP.NET MVC Server side Controls and on the click of the tab, I want to load content using Ajax, then how can I do that?

Comment: does clicking those tabs lead to a server side request ?

Comment: Did you have any javascript error in the console ? It would be easier with the code of your view.

Comment: No nothing at all i looked at the console and network i dint see any errors

Comment: Can we see the code of your view ? :D

Comment: @using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabstrip")     .Events(e => e
            .Select("tabstrip_select")
    )
    .Items(items =>{
        items.Add().Text("Item 1")
            .Selected(true)
            .Content(@<text>
                    <div>
                        <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
                    </div>
                  </text>);
        items.Add().Text("Item 2")
        .Selected(true)
        .Content(@<text>
            <div>
                <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
            </div>
            </text>);
    })
)

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue ?

Comment: No, not enough details to figure out the issue. In a javascript console, can you try checking the details of the tabstrip ? Not sure if the command is the same (I'm using Telerik MVC, not Kendo), is $("#tabstrip").data("tTabStrip") giving the details of the tabstrip ?

Comment: I included the files in another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704346/asp-net-mvc-tabstrip-doesnt-switch-tabs